# Predicting outcome of games - how to make team 1/2 interchangable

Tags: machine-learning

Currently I'm writing some models to predict outcomes of team games, but I'm having a hard time featurizing the teams so that the order of teams doesn't matter.

For example, currently I duplicate all the data and reverse it to reduce the effect of ordering on the outcome, but that's not proving perfect. If I have "Ravens vs Panthers = Panthers win", I also put in "Panthers vs Ravens = Panthers wins".

When I then go to my model and ask for the output of Panthers vs Ravens and Ravens vs Panthers, I get different (but similar) results. For example the probabilities of Panther's winning may be 75% in the first ane 72% in the second.

How else might I make it 100% ambiguous as to which team is team 1 and which is team 2?

Comment: A home team advantage may apply, and be a learnable thing, so this need for symmetry may not be so important in sporting fixtures. But otherwise very interesting question, could apply in many A vs B predictions.

Answer (score 1):

Home field advantage is incredibly important in sports. If you always put the home team in the first column, your model will adjust the bias term accordingly. I've been doing this successfully for NBA and MLB models for several years now. Making the first team the home team also eliminates the need for an explicit home indicator variable and you'll be able to use "half" of the data like you've described.

For rare neutral games like the Superbowl, you would need to create a mirror image of the data. In other words, present two rows for each game (team-A,team-B;team-B,team-A). When it's time to score you model, you can just arbitrarily pick one of the two records because they represent mirror opposite of the same thing. I've done this before for March Madness basketball games (all neutral courts), and this year (2016) my March Madness model was in the top 10% in Kaggle, so the technique works.

Home field advantage is just one of the variables you'll need to make a good predictive model, but that's an answer for another question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to average the predictions from "Team A vs Team B" and "Team B vs Team A" as inputs, and consider that part of your algorithm. You are already doing something similar when augmenting training data by considering both arrangements. This solution is also used by image classification models, which may output predictions averaged over more than one random patch from an input image, to get better translation invariance.

Inherently the problem you face is one of dimensionality - the input features are linked by some symmetry (e.g. Team A's defensive strength is equivalent to Team B's defensive strength), but this is not encoded into the learning model. Depending on your model class, you might be able to link weights or make adjustments to the features to better encode the symmetry. But this is a lot more work than creating a simple meta-model that predicts on both input arrangements.

Another simple alternative is to have a sorting algorithm apply between the features, such that which is Team A and which Team B as presented to the ML and prediction is decided by some function of the feature values (e.g. always make the team with highest value of a specific predictive feature the first team). This makes the training and prediction deterministic and avoids the issue of needing to treat the teams equivalently. In effect it breaks the symmetry, instead of "Team A" and "Team B" features you have "Team with highest X" and "Team with lowest X" features, and predict whether "Team with highest X" will win. A disadvantage of this approach is that which feature or rule you pick to sort by becomes a meta-param of your ML routine. It may help to pick a feature with a known strong influence on the result (sorting by team name is not likely to be effective).